# Set Secure Flag For Cookies In Flask-Security

Tags: security, cookies, flask, session-cookies, flask-security

I am doing server security testing and at every server security testing website it tells me that cookies are being created without the `secure flag`

The message is specifically:

```
The cookie is missing the Secure flag, make sure it does not store sensitive information.
```

I am using Flask and Flask-Security for creating sessions. I've looked through the docs but cannot find anything on the secure flag.

Does anyone know if this has to be within flask-security or outside? If in flask-security, how do I add this secure flag?

Comment: This also comes up when using Kali Linux penetration and server information gathering tools so I'm assuming it is an exploitable weakness which could cause problems in the future.

Comment: It's exploitable indeed, but really hard if your domain is on the HTTPS preload list.